# jQuery Datatable not sorting on the basis of custom attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I am filling an HTML table using foreach loop in the Razor view. On the frontend, I have sort functionality implemented(using jQuery Datatable) on a column which has additional data other than the integer on the basis of which I want to sort.

The issue is that it is not getting sorted on the basis of integral value, but randomly.

According to its official website, jQuery Datatable achieves sorting in this case by specifying the custom attribute by the name of "data-order" and then assign it the integral value. Somehow, it is not working.
I found a lot of solution in case the HTML table is getting filled by the data returned through Ajax call, but in my case, it is through MVC Razor engine.
Am I missing anything?

Here's the code in cshtml file. I want to sort it by the Count Column :-

```
<table datatable="full" datatable-filter-text="Filter by Customer:">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th no-sort>
                @if (Model.Documents.Any())
                { 
                    <input select-all type="checkbox" />
                }
            </th>
            <th class="nowrap">
                Document Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Customer
            </th>
            <th>
                Count
            </th>
            <th>
                Created
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var doc in Model.Documents)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedIds" value="@doc.Id" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Detail(doc.Id)">
                    @doc.Number</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @doc.Customer
            </td>
            <td data-order="@doc.Count">
                @doc.Count
                <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"  style="float:left"
                   title="Count" 
                   ui-qtip-ajax 
                   ui-qtip-position-at="top center" 
                   ui-qtip-position-my="bottom center" 
                   rel="@Url.Action("GetCount",
                       new
                       {
                           id = doc.Id,
                           Code = Model.Code
                       })" >
                </a>
                <div class="invisible">
                    @{ Html.RenderAction("GetCount",
                     new
                     {
                         id = doc.Id,
                         Code = Model.Code,
                         DisplayPlainText = true
                     });}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @doc.CreatedDate
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's how this particular Column looks like, after getting rendered on Google Chrome :-

```
<th class="ui-state-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                            Count
                        <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></div></th>
```

Comment: Put the code on here so we can help fix it, otherwise it is difficult for us to help properly.  Include the view/html if it is as it seems, relevant to the question.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Code inserted

Comment: And the datatable code?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There's no Datatable code. All I can see here is that some jQuery Datatables scripts are referenced and when the the page is rendered, this column has an attribute "DataTables_sort_wrapper", which is there in jquery DT. I might be wrong, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: dude i guess the table header th no-sort is preventing you from sorting + its a good practice to define your plugin initialization within script where you want some advance control over the plugin

Comment: @RAHULSR Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated the description. The issue is that it is not getting sorted on the basis of integral value, but randomly.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Added further description about how this column looks like, after getting rendered on chrome.

Comment: Is there a reason why you dont use the server side sorting ? For example @foreach (var doc in Model.Documents.OrderBy(i => i.Count) or better yet do the sorting in the controller ?

Comment: This [example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) shows an example of HTML5 attributes.  Above you show how the header is rendered.  What we need to see is examples of how the `Count` column is rendered, ie, what does the `data-order` attribute look like.  Somewhere you have Datatables init code - please post that.  When you try sorting the `Count` column what order is it in and what order do you expect - post examples.  Its hard to help without specific information.